# Does the SSTable change when I update a column?

Tags: cassandra

I understand that all insert operations will come to commitlog first, and `Memtable` second,  after that it will be compacted to `SSTable`.

After compaction to `SSTable`, I perform an update operation for an existing column. 
Must the `SSTable` be changed to update the value of that column?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/MemtableSSTable says:

> Once flushed, SSTable files are immutable; no further writes may be done

Your updated value will be written to commitlog, and a memtable, and will eventually be flushed to a new SSTable on-disk. Later, this SSTable may be merged with other SSTables to form a new larger SSTable (and the old ones will be discarded) - this is the compaction stage.

Answer (score 1):

Answering your follow-up question: yes, and no - your values may end up in different SSTables until they are compacted, but you don't need to wait until a compaction to get the 'true' value, because the various versions of your value are timestamped, so Cassandra can return the most recent.